# Mono through FastCGI on nginx

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, mono, arch-linux

I'm going through http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx and can't get it to work. The FastCGI server seems to be running. The following is from the error log:

> upstream sent unexpected FastCGI record: 3 while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.125, server: arch, request: "GET /Default.aspx HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "arch"

Command used to start the server (I've tried server2 and server4, using a simple .NET 2.0 or .NET 4.0 project):

> fastcgi-mono-server2 /applications=arch:/:/var/www/test/public/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /stopable=True

nginx config:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name arch;

    access_log /var/www/test/log/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/test/log/error.log;

    location /
    {
        root /var/www/test/public;
        index index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;
        fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          "";
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Using xsp4 works fine, I can browse the site.

I've enabled FastCGI logging, this is the output:

```
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Accepting an incoming connection.
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Notice  Beginning to receive records on connection.
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Record received. (Type: BeginRequest, ID: 1, Length: 8)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Record received. (Type: Params, ID: 1, Length: 386)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Record received. (Type: Params, ID: 1, Length: 0)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Read parameter. (PATH_INFO = )
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Read parameter. (SCRIPT_FILENAME = /var/www/test/public/Home)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Read parameter. (HTTP_HOST = arch)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Read parameter. (HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Read parameter. (HTTP_ACCEPT = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Read parameter. (HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = en-gb,en;q=0.5)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Read parameter. (HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = gzip, deflate)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Read parameter. (HTTP_CONNECTION = keep-alive)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Read parameter. (HTTP_COOKIE = ASP.NET_SessionId=2C3D702C9B0F23F69B80820B)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Error   Failed to process connection. Reason: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   Record sent. (Type: EndRequest, ID: 1, Length: 8)
[2012-04-15 23:51:18Z] Debug   The FastCGI connection has been closed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two additional FastCGI parameters are required.

```
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT "80";
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
```

Credit goes to KnyghtMare from the #mono IRC channel for his test script. By elimination, the required parameters for the nginx conf were found. Usage note: you might have to change the IP and port number on the last line, and `HTTP_HOST`.

```
SERVER_SOFTWARE="lighttpd/1.4.26" \
SERVER_NAME="127.0.0.1" \
GATEWAY_INTERFACE="CGI/1.1" \
SERVER_PORT="80" \
SERVER_ADDR="127.0.0.1" \
REMOTE_PORT="28886" \
REMOTE_ADDR="127.0.0.1" \
SCRIPT_NAME="/" \
PATH_INFO="" \
SCRIPT_FILENAME="/var/www/" \
DOCUMENT_ROOT="/var/www/" \
REQUEST_URI="/" \
QUERY_STRING="" \
REQUEST_METHOD="GET" \
REDIRECT_STATUS="200" \
SERVER_PROTOCOL="HTTP/1.1" \
HTTP_HOST="arch" \
HTTP_CONNECTION="keep-alive" \
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL="max-age=0" \
HTTP_USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11" \
HTTP_ACCEPT="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" \
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING="gzip,deflate" \
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE="en-US,en;q=0.8" \
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET="ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:9000
```

After some more modifications to get resource files working, this is the current configuration:

```
server
{
        listen 80;
        server_name arch;

        access_log /var/www/test/log/access.log;
        error_log /var/www/test/log/error.log debug;

        root /var/www/test/public;

        location /
        {
                try_files $uri @proxy;
        }

        location @proxy
        {
                fastcgi_index /Home;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO "";
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```